# PdfBox flatten pdf does not remove acroform elements

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a pdf with a lot of acroforms, I do some manipulation on it which results in a new pdf. 
So I have PDF-1 (which is the original one )and PDF-2 (just a duplication of PDF-1), now I want to merge them. Both PDFs have some acroforms for example: field_a, field_2...

Before I merge them I flatten PDF-1, because I only want to have acrofields from PDF-2. When I check then my new merged PDF I can see that there are no visible fields on on the pages from PDF-1 and there are fields on pages of fields of PDF-2. At the first look it seems ok, but when I inspect the fields I can see  that the merger has renamed all the fields for PDF-2 e.g. field_a_dummy123, field_b_dummy232 ...

It seems to me, that flattening does not remove the fields and thats why the PDFMerger from PDFBox will rename the fields for PDF-2 because acrofields need to be unique. Is there a way to completely remove the acroforms of PDF-1?

```
@Test
public void flattenAndMerge() throws IOException {
    File testForm = new File(classLoader.getResource("./TestForm.pdf").getFile());

    byte[] testFormAsByte = Files.readAllBytes(testForm.toPath());
    byte[] testFormAsByte2 = Files.readAllBytes(testForm.toPath());

    PDDocument pdf1 = PDDocument.load(testFormAsByte);
    PDAcroForm acroform = pdf1.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    acroform.flatten();
    Path flattendedPdf = Files.createTempFile("flatten", ".pdf");
    pdf1.save(flattendedPdf.toFile());


    PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
    merger.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(flattendedPdf)));
    merger.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(testFormAsByte2));
    merger.setDestinationFileName("./build/flattenAndMerge.pdf");
    merger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());

}
```

I am using PDFBox 2.0.8.

This is the input file: https://ufile.io/6etxp
Here is the result of the test: https://ufile.io/bh94n

As I could see the problem only occures with checkboxes, normal text fields will be removed correctly

Comment: What version are you using? Please share the PDF files.

Comment: I have edited my post and added the information

Comment: Indeed, there is a bug, and I assume it is due to problems handling non-trivial field hierarchies: The checkbox fields are not top-level fields but they are located under the top level node "cb_a". In the merge they are not only renamed but also added to the list of top-level form fields; this actually is not valid as they still have a **Parent** reference to "cb_a". You might want to try with PDFs with trivial form hierarchies first, and PDFBox has an issue to fix... ;)

Comment: Probably a bug in `mergeAcroForm()`. Please open an issue in [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX) and attach your files there. In the components, choose Acroform + Utilities.

Comment: Ok, added the bug there: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4066

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in a comment:

Indeed, this is a bug. It is not, though, as the OP has assumed *that flattening does not remove the fields*, it is a problem of the merging code in `PDFMergerUtility.mergeAcroForm`.

The underlying problem is in the handling of non-trivial field hierarchies: In the sample source document shared by the OP the checkbox fields are not top-level fields but they are located under the top level node "cb_a".

In the merged document they are not only renamed but also added to the list of top-level form fields; this actually is not valid as they still have a Parent reference to "cb_a".

This bug currently is discussed and resolved in the context of the Apacha Jira entry [PDFBOX-4066](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4066).